# What do the dots and arrows on this article mean?

Tags: functions

I'm [reading an article](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf) on how I can implement collision detection in my games.

It's a really good article. However, some of the maths is confusing me:

---

[image]

---

What do the dots after N mean? I've seen posts on this site that say that it is a multiply function, however that would make no sense because he uses a star for multiplication as well. Some other posts say that it is like a cast `()`, however considering it is already in a cast, then I'd be really confused as to what is the case.

Also, what do the arrows mean? Some articles have said that it means "If and only if" - Does that mean that it only does the calculation on the second line if the one on the first line is true?

Comment: It is probably hard to do collision detection if you don't know any vector algebra.

Comment: @GEdgar Then i'll learn. And I just now learned one more thing by asking this question. I know that it'll be hard, but as a game programmer, I need to understand all this stuff. And unfortunately high school doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using the dot to denote the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of vectors. The $\implies$ means that the formula at the head of the arrow is a consequence of the formula at the tail. It is read as "implies".

**Example**

$$x+1=2\implies x=1$$

reads as "$x=1$ is a consequence of $x+1=2$". By that we mean (whether true or not) that in any universe, no matter what $x,+,=,1,2$ mean, as long as they satisfy the usual properties we assume them to have, then if $x+1=2$ occurs then necessarily $x=1$ occurs.

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps worth adding: the "if and only if" arrow would be $\iff$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain exactly what do you mean by "Consequence of the formula"?

Comment: @user2722083 It means that current expression follows from previous one, or (the same): "if previous is true then current is true as well (visa versa is not correct in general case)", or you just may read this arrow as "hence".